# How accurate is the scale of Google Satellite Photos?

Tags: google-maps

Given a particular zoom level, how accurate is the scale provided by the satellite view in google maps?

Can one use it to ~accurately determine the square footage of a given building in the picture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The imagery is very accurate, and at the finest zoom levels (19 or 20), you will be able to perform area calculation with great precision. The location information in Google maps would definitely be more accurate than trying to get readings using a handheld GPS device (there are some app out there that let you walk around a perimeter setting waypoints, and then calculating the internal area based on those waypoints).

Here is a relatively painless utility that demonstrates this:

http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-area-calculator-tool.htm

One issue if you are trying to calculate square footage using the imagery however would be determining the number of stories.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the accuracy.  At the 200 ft. zoom level I superimposed the scale over Rice Stadium in Houston and it shows the playing field as a little over 200 ft. long and 50 meters wide. That means the width is about right but the length is way off since the standard football field is 300 ft. long.  Probably has something to do with the angle of the photo.  If the satellite is directly overhead it's probably more accurate.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

the graphic scale is not consistent as you zoom in and out.
I placed two zoom images into a CAD program and sized the images by measuring the graphic scale.  I got two different sized maps.

Comment: @PatrickQ: It is an answer. It may not be obvious that it is an answer by reading it out of context of the question, but the user is trying to say "The scale is not accurate at all." with anecdotal evidence as proof.